# How to get date added or edited contact with CNContact in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, addressbook, cncontact

I have array contacts fetched using CNContactStore. I want get date added to addressbook. But when using CNContactDatesKey, result allway is 0.
I hope you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in the new CNContact framework, although it was possible in the addressbook framework , here is a [reference](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/16049), also you can try the method suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33429047/2591165)

Comment: @AbdAl-rhmanTaherBadary have you noticed any update on this? Can't find anything new... :o(

Comment: @Dirk not that i know of.